# creating jsf view/Component tree from the xhtml file

Tags: java, jsf-2

I need to access jsf pages component tree on application start up. I found this source on the net

```
   UIViewRoot viewRoot = context.getApplication().getViewHandler().createView(context, "/path/to/some.xhtml");
```

but the resulting viewRoot doesn't have any children. 
Does anybody know what is the best way to do it?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to **build** the view. You can use [`ViewDeclarationLanguage#buildView()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/ViewDeclarationLanguage.html#buildView%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot%29) for this. Here's an extract of its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/ViewDeclarationLanguage.html#buildView%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot%29) (emphasis mine):

> Take any actions specific to this VDL implementation to cause the argument `UIViewRoot` which must have been created via a call to [`createView(javax.faces.context.FacesContext, java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/ViewDeclarationLanguage.html#createView%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String%29), **to be populated with children**.

Thus, this should do:

```
String viewId = "/path/to/some.xhtml";
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ViewHandler viewHandler = context.getApplication().getViewHandler();

UIViewRoot view = viewHandler.createView(context, viewId);
viewHandler.getViewDeclarationLanguage(context, viewId).buildView(context, view);
// view should now have children.
```

You can by the way also use the [`ViewDeclarationLanguage#createView()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/view/ViewDeclarationLanguage.html#createView%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String%29) directly to create the view instead of the [`ViewHandler#createView()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#createView%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String%29) shorthand.

```
String viewId = "/path/to/some.xhtml";
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ViewDeclarationLanguage vdl = context.getApplication().getViewHandler().getViewDeclarationLanguage(context, viewId);

UIViewRoot view = vdl.createView(context, viewId);
vdl.buildView(context, view);
// view should now have children.
```