# Understanding JSF Lifecycle phases with & without Redirection

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, navigation, lifecycle

Suppose there are 2 JSF pages & a backing bean

*index.xhtml-* with view parameters & a form

*Backing bean-*  action method with navigation to *result.xhtml* from *index.xhtml* with `NO REDIRECTION`

*result.xhtml-* no form but outputting some text

Consider a simple case

Fire a GET request to *index.xhtml*-

Something like this with view parameters-

*http://localhost:8080/Leonard/faces/ch2/ch2_8/index.xhtml?playernameparam=HAMZA&playersurnameparam=YOUSUF*

*Phases executed-*

[image]

*Response-*

[image]

*Hit Submit-*

[image]

*Phases executed-*

[image]

NOTE: It was a *POSTBACK*, the lifecycle phases were executed for *POST* request to *index.xhtml*

*Response-*

[image]

The response contains the contents of *result.xhtml* page, which were then clearly reflected in the browser window. As it was rendered, the lifecycle must have executed for result.xhtml view too. WHY DON"T I SEE THE PHASES for this view in the console?

I know very well that with redirection, on POSTBACK, the render response phase for *index.xhtml* will be skipped and then all the phases for *result.xhtml* will be fired.

Comment: I guess your concrete question boils down to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11277366

Comment: @BalusC: Absolutely no, Bauke. I know those things very well. What I am asking here is that when there is no redirection, & on performing navigation from index.xhtml to result.xhtml, the contents of result.xhtml will be reflected in the browser window without the current URL(i.e for result.xhtml). To render this view(result.xhtml), it must have gone through lifecycle phases. Where are those? I mean phase listener didn't get fired or else it must have been shown in the console/

Comment: The lifecycle is request based not view based. A redirect creates a new request (as explained in link).

Comment: @BalusC: Yes, that was something I was looking for, which indeed didn't hit my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to expect that the lifecycle is view based. This will indeed cause confusion.

In fact, the lifecycle is request based, not view based. That should clear up everything. If you think about it, it's really unnecessary to redo entire cycle of collecting, converting and validating request parameters and update model values and invoke action during the very same HTTP request.

#### See also:

- [What is the difference between redirect and navigation/forward and when to use what?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11277366)
- [What's the view build time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890433/whats-the-view-build-time)

Comment: @downvoter: Who downvoted this answer? Atleast have courtesy enough to drop a reason for this.