# Render and build time in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have serious problem to understand this notion of build and render time. No matter what I read about this, I don't know when I read a piece of xhtml code if it's going to be executed in build or render time. For exemple, I'm using `DynaForm` of Primefaces Extensions. I don't know if all dynaFormControl are present in JSF component tree, or only those defined by the `DynaFormModel`

Comment: Which of those is most helpful in understanding and answering your concrete question about build vs render time? http://stackoverflow.com/q/31890433 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/3342984?

Comment: I'm just quoting what you said "...already ends up as-is in the JSF component tree whereby the very same <h:outputText> component is during view render time being reused to generate HTML output based on current iteration round..." Does it mean, there is one instance used of HtmloutputText contained in the JSF component tree?

Comment: You understood it correctly.

Comment: But how to distinguish a "tag" used at build and render time? For exemple, ui:include is processed at build time and ui:repeat at render time: how to do you know that?

Comment: Whether the Java class behind the tag extends `TagHandler` or `UIComponent`. See also links in the first paragraph of answer on http://stackoverflow.com/q/3342984